# Function with input as a list that doesn't give me :takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given. Error

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, input

I need to create a function that allows for a list for the input, then breaks apart list and prints them each separately:

```
def clas(list_):  
    x=list_  
    for n in x:  
        print (x)
```

I had it working with something similar to this for the first part.  clas('1','2','bob') output would be:
'1'
'2'
'bob'

Comment: `print (n)`you need to print each element, not the entire list. Also, don't call it `list`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, here are a couple:

```
def clas(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        print(item)

the_list = [1, 2, 'Bob']
clas(the_list)
```

The print function itself is capable of handling this:

```
def clas(my_list):
    print(*my_list, sep='\n')
```

If you really want to invoke it as:

```
clas(1, 2, 'Bob')
```

Then we can do:

```
def clas(*args):
    for item in args:
        print(item)
```

Or:

```
def clas(*args):
    print(*args, sep='\n')
```